# Want SQL query to be modified or corrected

Tags: sql, oracle

When I am running this query:

```
select sm.stylename, 
(select fieldvalue from auxiliaryfield af where af.stylename = sm.stylename and fieldlabel = 'Vendor Name') as "VENDOR NAME",
(select fieldvalue from auxiliaryfield af where af.stylename = sm.stylename and fieldlabel = 'Vendor Number') as "VENDOR NUMBER",
(select fieldvalue from auxiliaryfield af where af.stylename = sm.stylename and fieldlabel = 'Vendor Address') as "VENDOR ADDRESS",
(select fieldvalue from auxiliaryfield af where af.stylename = sm.stylename and fieldlabel = 'Factory Name') as "FACTORY NAME",
(select fieldvalue from auxiliaryfield af where af.stylename = sm.stylename and fieldlabel = 'Factory Address') as "FACTORY ADDRESS"
from stylemaster sm order by sm.stylename;
```

I get the error message:

```
"ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
01427. 00000-"single-row subquery returns more than one row"
```

Can you please help in resolving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

One of your subqueries is returning more than one value.  You can fix the symptom by adding `where rownum = 1` or an aggregation function:

```
select sm.stylename, 
       (select max(fieldvalue) from auxiliaryfield af where af.stylename = sm.stylename and fieldlabel = 'Vendor Name') as "VENDOR NAME",
       (select max(fieldvalue) from auxiliaryfield af where af.stylename = sm.stylename and fieldlabel = 'Vendor Number') as "VENDOR NUMBER",
       (select max(fieldvalue) from auxiliaryfield af where af.stylename = sm.stylename and fieldlabel = 'Vendor Address') as "VENDOR ADDRESS",
       (select max(fieldvalue) from auxiliaryfield af where af.stylename = sm.stylename and fieldlabel = 'Factory Name') as "FACTORY NAME",
       (select max(fieldvalue) from auxiliaryfield af where af.stylename = sm.stylename and fieldlabel = 'Factory Address') as "FACTORY ADDRESS"
from stylemaster sm
order by sm.stylename;
```

That will get rid of the problem, but you might want to investigate why the duplicates are showing up to begin with.

EDIT:

If `max()` doesn't work on your data types, then use `rownum = 1`:

```
select sm.stylename, 
       (select (fieldvalue) from auxiliaryfield af where af.stylename = sm.stylename and fieldlabel = 'Vendor Name' and rownum = 1) as "VENDOR NAME",
       (select (fieldvalue) from auxiliaryfield af where af.stylename = sm.stylename and fieldlabel = 'Vendor Number' and rownum = 1) as "VENDOR NUMBER",
       (select (fieldvalue) from auxiliaryfield af where af.stylename = sm.stylename and fieldlabel = 'Vendor Address' and rownum = 1) as "VENDOR ADDRESS",
       (select (fieldvalue) from auxiliaryfield af where af.stylename = sm.stylename and fieldlabel = 'Factory Name' and rownum = 1) as "FACTORY NAME",
       (select (fieldvalue) from auxiliaryfield af where af.stylename = sm.stylename and fieldlabel = 'Factory Address' and rownum = 1) as "FACTORY ADDRESS"
from stylemaster sm
order by sm.stylename;
```

Comment: When I ran the above mentioned query, I am getting the error message "ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:"

Comment: @omprakashv . . . Storing field values as `CLOB`s seems like overkill and generally a bad idea.